# I want just not showing this log (Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.)

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube

I want just not showing this log  in chrome

Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.

[image]

```html
     <iframe
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        :src="item.src"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;"
        allowfullscreen
     ></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code with the log suppressed in Chrome:

```html
<iframe
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    :src="item.src"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;"
    allowfullscreen
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-presentation"
></iframe>
```

I've added the `sandbox` attribute to the `iframe` tag with specific permissions to suppress the log in Chrome.

Comment: i'm sorry it's not working